# Joomla Blog override not working

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a joomla 8.2 site which I want to put a blog category override in.

It's been a while since I've done this but I thought I'd set it up correctly:

I copied components->com_content->views->category->tmpl->blog.php to

mytemplate->html->com_content->category->siteblog.php

when I go to: menu and create a category blog and I look in options for choose layout I don't see the alternative layout.  I'm obviously missing something :(

Can someone help!

Comment: You should use the Template - Styles - Overrides function to create the override, then just change the overridden layout you don't even need to rename it if you don't need both layouts (original and modified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a new layout, not overriding the existing blog.php, you can leave it in components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/ but you need to upload a siteblog.xml as well.